# Get latest 100MB Of text file in linux

Tags: linux, text, text-manipulation

How do I get the latest 100MB from a text log on Linux? Is there a tool for it, or could you point me on a script?

I have no programming experience on Shell Scripting, Perl or Python, and I don't want to install mono so I can write it in C#.

Thanks!!

Yvan Janssens

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this :

```
tail -c 104857600 yourFile
```

or if you're more confortable:

```
tail -c $[1024*1024*100] yourFile
```

---

**Resources :**

- [linux.die.net - tail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail)

Answer (score 2):

Use `tail`:

```
$ tail -c 104857600 your_file_name
```

Where `104857600` is 100MB in bytes.

Or:

```
$ tail -b 204800 your_file_name
```

Where `204800` is size in 512-byte block.